# How to run .sql script over Task Scheduler daily

Tags: postgresql, scheduled-tasks

I have a .sql script that executes a procedure in my postgres DB.

I want to execute this script every day so for that I want to use Task Scheduler. However I do not know how to set my script in order to be executed every day.

When I create a new Task , I import my .sql script in Actions but it doesn't work :

[Actions to set up?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZvbs.png)

**Does anyone know how to set a .sql script in Task Scheduler please?**

Comment: You need a SQL client, like psql, that executes your sql-file. The Task Schedular should make a call to this client and sql-file. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: I already have a .sql that executes with psql when I type : "\i ...path/myscript.sql" but I want to execute it daily with the Task Scheduler, my question is how to set a .sql script with Task Schedular?

Comment: Where do you start psql? That's not in the image that you shared, you only selected a plain SQL file. And without psql (or any other client) that will never be executed on the database.